# Grouping Age into custom Sections?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, data-science

I am reading a CSV of Users and trying to create an Age group into my new Dataframe. But I am getting Future warning and not the expected result. For me its hard to explain. Because of this i will show what I mean.

That is the Code. In the Comment section is something I tried but getting Future warning.

```
users = pd.read_csv('Users.csv')
group_names = ['[0-10]','[11-20]','[21-30]','[31-40]','[41-50],[51-60],[61-70],[71-80],[81-90],[91-100]']
bins = ([0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100])


ageGroup = users.groupby('Age').size()
# ageGroup = users.groupby((pd.cut(users.Age,bins),'Age')).sum()
print(ageGroup)
```

What Dataframe I get:

```
Age
0      7794612
6            1
13          14
14         260
```

What Dataframe I want:

```
Age           Frequency
[0 - 10]      7794613
[11 - 12]     274
```

Hopefully you guys can help me. I try so many things but for some Reason it does not work. I searched in Stackoverflow but I dont find anything. Please remind me if there is a way or a similar question on Stackoverflow.

Best Regards

Tobias

Comment: `usersDF` is undefined in your code. Post a testable fragment of `Users.csv`

Comment: It was just a test. I edit it because I renamed it. Sorry for confusing.

Comment: Use pd.cut() to bin the age and groupby that

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use `cut` for this. As in:

```
users["binned_ages"] = pd.cut(users["Age"], bins=[10,20,30,40,50,60,70])
```

[More on cut and bins here.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.cut.html)

You can then grouby on your bins.

```
ageGroup = users.groupby("binned_ages").size()
```

In a single line this would look like:

```
ageGroup = users.groupby(pd.cut(users["Ages"], bins=bins)).size()
```